# Angular 1/Ui-router - Pass data from resolve to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I want to pass a data (`contactName`) from the state to the controller by the resolves :

```
.state({
      name: 'contact.detail.overlay',
      abstract: true,
      component: 'overlayContent',
      resolve: {
        contactName: (originalContact, $rootScope, ContactService) => {
          $rootScope.contactName = ContactService.getContactName(originalContact)
          return $rootScope.contactName
        }
      }
    })
```

on my state all is correct, `contactName` is also correct, but it is not accessible in my `overlayContent` controller, do you have a solution to have `$rootScope.contactName` access in the controller ?

EDIT :
The controller :

```
class overlayContentComponent {

  constructor($state, $interpolate, $scope) {
    'ngInject'
    this.$scope = $scope
    this.$state = $state
    this.$interpolate = $interpolate
  }

  /**
   *
   * On initialization hook, let's check if an overlay title
   * has been defined for the current state.
   */

  $onInit() {
    const stateData = this.$state.current.data || { title: '' }
    this.overlayTitle = angular.isDefined(stateData.title) ? this.$interpolate(stateData.title)() : ''
  }
}

export const overlayContentComponent = {
  template: require('./overlay-content.html'),
  controller: overlayContentComponent
}
```

I can access `contactName` in my controller by `this.$scope.$root.contactName` but I would like to avoid `$scope.$root` by another alternative

Comment: Can you post your controller too please? What error, if any, is showing? Are you using /* ngInject */ in your resolve code, or your angularJS app in general?

Comment: @rrd The post has been modified with some more explanations

Answer (score 0):

Change your constructor:

```
constructor($state, $interpolate, $scope, contactName) {
  'ngInject';
  // The variable you want:
  this.contactName = contactName;
  this.$scope = $scope
  this.$state = $state
  this.$interpolate = $interpolate
}
```

The 'contactName' resolve should be injected now, into the controller for that state (where the resolve resides). This should allow you to access it in the controller, as above.